# Clearing multiple forms with jQuery / JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've got a resetForm() function that performs a bunch of tasks on quite a complicated set of forms.

Part of that function is clearing 3 separate forms on reset :

```
$('form#s1').each(function() { this.reset() });
$('form#s2').each(function() { this.reset() });
$('form#s3').each(function() { this.reset() });
```

This works fine, but while trying to slim down my code I noticed that this fails if I try to select all 3 forms at once :

```
$('form#s1','form#s2','form#s3').each(function() { this.reset() });
```

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Maybe try selecting them like this? `$('form#s1 , form#s2 , form#s3')`

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out.. Doh... Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
$('form#s1,form#s2,form#s3').each(function() { this.reset() });
```

Note that the value of the selector is all one string in CSV format. Here it is in action.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELwYva

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```
 $("form").trigger("reset");
```

Hope this helps you.